# Move content between SharePoint environments without upgrading?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2013

I was wondering if there is a way using .Net code that I could move content and sites from one SharePoint server to another if those SharePoint environments are on different versions (one being on SharePoint 2007 and one being on SharePoint 2010, for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to migrate sites from 2007 to 2010 is via a database detach upgrade. That doesn't involve writing much of any code at all, except, I guess if you wanted to automate the process of some of these intermediate steps. In a nutshell:

1. Move all of the sites that you want to move to the 2010 farm onto one or more content databases in 2007.
2. Go into SQL and back up the DBs in question.
3. Take the .bak files SQL created and move them into your SQL instance for your 2010 farm.
4. Restore those DBs onto the new SQL instance.
5. Run [this command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607581%28v=office.14%29.aspx) from Powershell.

   ```
   Mount-SPContentDatabase "YourDBName" -WebApplication http://webapplication.com -DatabaseServer "yourserver" -UpdateUserExperience
   ```

SharePoint will automatically update these sites to 2010 as they are mounted. If you leave the `-UpdateUserExperience` flag off, the sites won't add the ribbon and will otherwise look like they're still using 2007. Otherwise... if your farm account on the 2007 farm is different than the farm account on the 2010 farm, you may need to give the 2010 farm account access to the DBs you're migrating before you copy the DBs over. Needless to say, SharePoint won't be able to mount anything it can't access.

Answer (score 1):

You can also explore the possibility of using third party tools like ShareGate for data migration.

http://en.share-gate.com/

Comment: Basically I'd like to know, academically, how one would do this kind of thing themselves?